# React Helmet work perfectly on localhost but on cpanel rener null for the meta tags

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

So i tried use react helmet like this in my component :

```
 <Helmet>
<title>EXAMPLE</title>
<meta name="description" content="EXAMPLE" />
<meta itemprop="name" content="EXAMPLE" />
<meta itemprop="description" content="EXAMPLE" />
<meta itemprop="image" content="EXAMPLE" />
etc ...
</Helmet>
```

**everything work perfect on localhost but when extract the build and upload it to cpanel , shared the link on facebook and test meta on metatags.io I always get null for the meta**

Comment: i just noticed that the head section load after the HTML page load its like a little bit late any solution ?

Comment: My assumption is the you're going to need to Server-Side Render those tags if you want them to load in time for Facebook to grab them.